# Convert brightness numbers to ASCII characters in python

Tags: python

I am doing programming project ASCII art in python . So far I managed to convert RGB tuples to into single brightness numbers. Next step is to convert the numbers to to ASCII characters. I am stuck because I do not know what I should do next. I have to select ASCII character to each numbers, range of the numbers are in 0,255. I would like to get some hints how can I done this.

This is my code so far.

```py
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("IMG_3021.jpg")

#print(im.size)

#im.show()

def load_pixel():

    im = Image.open("IMG_3021.jpg")

    x = list(im.getdata())
    pixel = [int(sum(i)/3) for i in x]
    for i in iter(pixel):
        print(i)

   # return pixel
    
#    for pixel in iter(x):
#        x = sum(pixel)//3
#        x = (x * len(pixel_ascii_map)) // 255
#        ascii_val = pixel_ascii_map[x]
#        print(ascii_val)

print(load_pixel())
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from PIL import Image

pixel_ascii_map = "`^\",:;Il!i~+_-?][}{1)(|\\/tfjrxnuvczXYUJCLQ0OZmwqpdbkhao*#MW&8%B@$"

def load_pixel():
  im = Image.open("IMG_3021.jpg")
  x = list(im.getdata())
  for pixel in iter(x):
    x = sum(pixel) // 3 # integer division
    ascii_val = pixel_ascii_map[x]
    print(ascii_val)
```

Beware that your ascii map has not enough length (pixels are in range 0-255). So in order to prevent it, you could rescale the `x` value in order to stay in the map range:

```py
from PIL import Image

pixel_ascii_map = "`^\",:;Il!i~+_-?][}{1)(|\\/tfjrxnuvczXYUJCLQ0OZmwqpdbkhao*#MW&8%B@$"

def load_pixel():
  im = Image.open("IMG_3021.jpg")
  x = list(im.getdata())
  for pixel in iter(x):
    x = sum(pixel) // 3 # integer division
    x = (x * len(pixel_ascii_map)) // 255 # rescaling
    ascii_val = pixel_ascii_map[x]
    print(ascii_val)
```

Beware that by doing `sum(pixel) // 3` you are actually grayscaling your image, so you will loose any color information.

Comment: (I've converted this to C#) For some reason, using this code snippet only seems to give me 'v'.

Comment: @The_Game12 It's hard to guess what's wrong without some code. I've translated it, check some differences with that of yours: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AaUqFn

Comment: I figured it out :)